# How do I add a different monitor resolution to NVidia X Server Settings' list

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, resolution, nvidia-graphics-card, xubuntu

I've got two monitors connected to the same PC; one directly via DVI, the other through a KVM switch on a (blue) VGA cable.
I just installed Xubuntu 11.10 on it, installed the current nvidia drivers, and using the `NVidia X Server Settings` applet, I've configured them.  I'm using a TwinView configuration, so that I can drag windows from one monitor to the other, etc.

The DVI-connected monitor is recognized correctly and set to 1024x768. The VGA-connected, however, lists a slew of resolutions, but not the correct one (1280x1024).  I've now set it to 1280x960, but everything is slightly blurry since it's not the monitor's native resolution.
The listed resolutions are 1440x900, 1360x768, 1280x960, 1152x864, 1024x768, 832x624, 800x600, 720x450, 680x384, 640x480, 512x384.

Does anybody know how and where I can configure my machine so that the main monitor works at its native resolution?

**Edit:** This is currently the contents of my `xorg.conf`:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 280.13  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-03.nvidia.com)  Wed Jul 27 17:15:58 PDT 2011

# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 280.13  (buildd@yellow)  Fri Aug  5 12:31:28 UTC 2011

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "CRT-1"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 60.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "COMPAQ 1520"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 60.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 530"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 530"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "metamodes" "DFP: nvidia-auto-select +1360+0, CRT: 1360x768_60 +0+0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "CRT: 1280x960 +0+0, DFP: nvidia-auto-select +1360+0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "CRT: 1280x960 +0+0, DFP: nvidia-auto-select +1280+0"
# Removed Option "TwinView" "1"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "CRT: 1280x960 +0+0, DFP: nvidia-auto-select +1280+192"
# Removed Option "TwinView" "0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "CRT: 1280x960 +0+0"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "1"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "CRT: 1280x960 +0+0, DFP: nvidia-auto-select +1280+192"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes      "1280x1024" "1280x1024" "1152x864" "1024x768" "800x600" "640x480"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be relatively easy to fix.

Once I connected the monitor directly to the computer, the driver was able to read the monitor's [EDID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data).  I saved the settings, and now it works fine even when connected through the KVM switch.

The main problem was that I needed to specify different frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

Add it in `xorg.conf` directly or use `nvidia-xconfig --mode=1280x1024`

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  _How_ do I add it in `xorg.conf` directly?  I can't see anywhere likely, except in one place where it's already listed (to no avail).  I'll add the contents of my `xorg.conf` to the question.

Comment: Edit the metamodes for Monitor0 (the one called CRT-1). `man xorg.conf` and the [nVidia documenation](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/180.22/README/chapter-13.html) are also helpful.

Comment: ah, thanks a lot for the link to the docs.  I'll be playing with that.